# M24LR16E Drivers not being read with NFC on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nfc, core-nfc

I am trying to read a type of driver that uses the M24LR16E chip and I'm having some trouble reading it on iOS using the NFCCore library. I'm using the NCFTagReaderSession as the session for the communication with the NFC on iOS and the drivers on my Xamarin app and I'm able to read the drivers with ST25DVC chip without any issues but not the same with the M24LR16E. I know that the M24LR16E use a double byte addressing and rely on using the Protocol Extension, but on NFCTagReaderSession they introduced the reading/writing on the ISO15693 (which includes the M24LR16E).

I've read in some forums that years ago people were having issues with these drivers but right now it seems no one is talking about it. Can someone help me with some information if it's possible to read such drivers?

I've tried these approaches:

1. I used CustomCommand method to send a custom command that was the same on my Android version where the driver was able to be read with no success
2. I've used an external app just to test if the communication with the driver was possible, but only the command "2B" (which is for the System Information) gave me a response, the reading and writing were giving a "Tag Connection lost" error.
3. I tried using the Command.Reading as standard reading command but to no avail.
4. Also tried reading with every possible combination on the RequestFlag inside the CustomCommand (using the ProtocolExtension, High DataRate, Options, etc.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.